# adding up values in Firebase without replacing existing data into a textview using array

Tags: android, arrays, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase database. This is basically for a barber shop. So this is all the bookings which have been served (confirm). It currently holds the Uid of the user as a child. Within this child it has values other id's which each have the same value field names.

So I need the total sum of how much the barber has earned. This is by the totaCost values of each to be added up with the other and be set to a text view. For example, since there is 3 parts you get 8+12+4=24

Below is the image of my database:

[image: database:]

Comment: add your database schema so we can help you

Comment: the link is the image of the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
//declaration
float total = 0F;

 mRef.child("confirm").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    for (DataSnapshot snapChild : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                        total += snapChild.child("totalCost").getValue(Float.class);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: having problems with the declaration of the float total. It says variable 'total' is accessed within inner class, it needs declared final. when I have done the following changes. it gives

Comment: declare it above the `onCreate()`